# C# List Remove Case-Insensitive

Tags: c#, list, compare, case

I want to remove a word from a List. The problem is that the word to delete is user input, and it should be case insensitive.

I know how to do case insensitive comparisons. But this doesn't seem to work.

```
List<string> Words = new List<string>();
Words.Add("Word");
Words.Remove("word", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To remove all

```
Words.RemoveAll(n => n.Equals("word", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

to remove first occurrence, like `Remove`:

```
Words.RemoveAt(Words.FindIndex(n => n.Equals("word", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
```

Comment: What does: 'n => n.'     mean? trying out right now btw.

Comment: It does work. But I dont understand what the n => n does. What is n?

Comment: This is [Lambda Expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). Basically you pass a method which will be called for every item, where `n` will that item passed into it. And method returns `true` or `false` depending if item matches your condition or not.

Comment: To clarify further, `n => n.Equals("word", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` is a lambda expression.  Essentially, a function literal.  The `n` at the very start is the parameter to the function, and everything after the `=>` is the result of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [RemoveAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method :

```
List<string> Words = new List<string>();
Words.Add("Word");
Words.RemoveAll(o => o.Equals("word", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension function that will do the same thing:

```
        public static void Remove(this List<string> words, string value, StringComparison compareType, bool removeAll = true)
    {
        if (removeAll)
            words.RemoveAll(x => x.Equals(value, compareType));
        else
            words.RemoveAt(words.FindIndex(x => x.Equals(value, compareType)));
    }
```

As an added bonus, this removes values that start with a specified string:

```
        public static void RemoveStartsWith(this List<string> words, string value, StringComparison compareType, bool removeAll = true)
    {
        if (removeAll)
            words.RemoveAll(x => x.StartsWith(value, compareType));
        else
            words.RemoveAt(words.FindIndex(x => x.StartsWith(value, compareType)));
    }
```

Usage example:

```
wordList.Remove("text to remove", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
wordList.RemoveStartsWith("text to remove", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```